# Obtener elementos de una tabla si estos no aparecen en otra tabla dado un rango de fechas

Tags: laravel-7

Hola estoy intentando obtener elementos de una tabla pero la condicion es que no pueden estar en una tabla de reservaciones dado un rango de fecha. Para obtener los elementos que estan en ese rango estoy usando la funcionalidad siguiente:

```
$rooms_no_avaible = \App\Models\Booking::whereDate('departure_date','>=' , '2023-10-21')
                                        ->whereDate('arrival_date','<=', '2023-10-28')->get();
```

Pero como pudiera obtener dado el resultado obetenido en `$rooms_no_avaible` las habitaciones que no estan en ese rango de fechas.

Tengo dos tablas independientes una que es `rooms` y otra que es `bookings`.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer lo siguente.

1. buscamos las habitaciones no disponibles y las juntamos en un array
2. usar ese array para buscar en la otra tabla

   ```
         $rooms_no_availables = \App\Models\Booking::whereDate('departure_date','>=' , '2023-10-21')
         ->whereDate('arrival_date','<=', '2023-10-28')->pluck('room_id');
   ```

Suponiendo que room_id   es el id de la habitación,
la función pluck() devuelve un array creado con los ids.

```
        $availables_rooms = \App\Models\Room::whereNotIn( 'id', $rooms_no_availables)->get();
```

whereNotIn de eloquent devuelve los registros con id diferentes a los almacenados en $rooms_no_availables

Espero te sirva. saludos